# Connecting to Weblogic JMS queue using Spring integrtion with Java DSL configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

How to create a JMS messagedriven adapter to connect to Oracle weblogic JMS queue using Spring integration with Java Integration DSL.

Comment: This is not a question. Please check [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks MarkusEgle !!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below code to connect to Weblogic JMS queue using Spring integrtion with Java dsl configuration.

1. Firstly , We need to create a connection factory & Destination Resolver  object which has to be passed to Jms messageDrivenChannelAdapter

   Below code is used to create a connectionFactory:

   ```
          import 
          org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer;
         import 
          org.springframework.jms.support.destination.DestinationResolver;
         import 
         org.springframework.jms.support.destination.JndiDestinationResolver;
        import java.util.Properties;
        import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
        import javax.jms.Destination;
        import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
        import javax.naming.Context;
        import javax.naming.InitialContext;
        import javax.naming.NameNotFoundException;
        import javax.naming.NamingException;
        import weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory;
        @Configuration
       @EnableJms
       public class JMSConfigurer  { 


       @Value("${spring.jms.url}")
       private String url;

       @Value("${spring.jms.username}")
       private String username;

       @Value("${spring.jms.password}")
       private String password;

       @Value("${spring.jms.connectionFactoryName}")
       private String connectionFactoryName;

       @Value("${spring.jms.queue}")
       private String mpiResponseQueue;


       private Properties getJNDiProperties() {

           final Properties jndiProps = new Properties();
           jndiProps.setProperty(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
           jndiProps.setProperty(Context.PROVIDER_URL, url);
           if (username != null && !username.isEmpty()) {
               jndiProps.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, username);
           }
           if (password != null && !password.isEmpty()) {
               jndiProps.setProperty(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
           }
           return jndiProps;

       }

       /**
        * Create connection factory.
        * 
        * @return
        */
       @Bean
       public ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory() {
           // JNDI connection factory name stored in weblogic.
           return lookupByJndiTemplate(connectionFactoryName, QueueConnectionFactory.class);
       }

       /**
        * Create InitialContext.
        * 
        * @return
        */
       @Bean
       public JndiTemplate jndiTemplate() {
           JndiTemplate jndiTemplate = new JndiTemplate();
           jndiTemplate.setEnvironment(getJNDiProperties());
           return jndiTemplate;
       }

        @Bean
       public Destination mpiResponseQueue() {
             return lookupByJndiTemplate(mpiResponseQueue, Destination.class);
       }
       /**
        * 
        * @param jndiName
        * @param requiredType
        * @return
        */
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       protected <T> T lookupByJndiTemplate(String jndiName, Class<T> requiredType) {

           try {
               Object located = jndiTemplate().lookup(jndiName);
               if (located == null) {
                   throw new NameNotFoundException("JNDI object with [" + jndiName + "] not found");
               }
               return (T) located;
           } catch (NamingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }

       /**
        * 
        * @param jndiName
        * @param requiredType
        * @return
        */
       @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
       protected final <T> T lookup(String jndiName, Class<T> requiredType) {

           try {
               InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(getJNDiProperties());
               Object located = initialContext.lookup(jndiName);
               if (located == null) {
                   throw new NameNotFoundException("JNDI object with [" + jndiName + "] not found");
               }
               return (T) located;
           } catch (NamingException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```

   ---

   2. In your main class of spring boot add the below code :

   `

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
      @IntegrationComponentScan

   public class JmsReaderApplication {
   @Autowired
   private javax.jms.ConnectionFactory queueConnectionFactory; @Autowired
   private Destination mpiResponseQueue;

   @Override
   protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
           return application.sources(JmsReaderApplication.class);
       }
   @Bean
   public IntegrationFlow jmsReader() {
       return IntegrationFlows
       .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(this.queueConnectionFactory)
           .destination(this.mpiResponseQueue))
       .channel("queureader")
       .get();
   }

   @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "queureader")
   public void Print(Message<?> msg)  {

       System.out.println(msg.getPayload().toString());
   }
   }
   ```

   ---

   3.Add this properties in your application.properties

   spring.jms.username= Username
   spring.jms.password= Password
   spring.jms.queue= Queue name
   spring.jms.url= Weblogic server url
   spring.jms.connectionFactoryName= Connectionfactory name ex jms/TestConnectionFactory

   ---

   4. Make sure to add the wlthint3client.jar oracle jar in your pom.xml.

   Hope this helps you ALL!!!